# Can 2.1-preview.3 or 2.1 form recognizer versions be used with powerskills code?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Is it possible to use powerskills code with  form recognizer 2.1-preview.3 or 2.1?
The 2.1-preview.1 is buggy and not that good, so can i use 2.1-preview.3 version in the powerskill? If yes the how/where can i change it?

Answer (score 1):

Changed to `azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.1.2` in the requirements.txt file in the powerskills code. This works for the 2.1-preview.3 version.